# Unhandled Exception: Exception: {error: entity validation failed, reasons: [invalid input type for 'brand']}

Tags: json, flutter, aqueduct

I'm trying to pass a Json body inside a Json body using flutter. 
The function is as follow:

```
  Future<String> postItem(Item item, Brand brand) async {
    var jsonob = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      'item_code': item.itemCode,
      'item_name': item.itemName,
      'part_no': item.partNo,
      'min_stock': int.parse(item.minStock),
      'brand': jsonEncode(brand)
    });
    print(jsonob); //for debugging
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      BASE_URL + "item",
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonob
    );
```

Brand the following function to encode to json:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": int.parse(this.brandId),
    "brand_name": this.brandName,
    "brand_code": this.brandCode,
    "brand_image": this.brandImage
  };
```

error message:
`E/flutter ( 1601): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: {error: entity validation failed, reasons: [invalid input type for 'brand']}`

output of print for jsonob:

`{"item_code":"item-001","item_name":"item123","part_no":"part123","min_stock":1,"brand":"{\"id\":1,\"brand_name\":\"BRANDA\",\"brand_code\":\"BRANDA\",\"brand_image\":\"null\"}"}`

I'm using the guidelines from here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data

The http server is created using Aqueduct.
I tried running the same http.post using POSTMAN and there was no error thrown, so I'm unsure what is causing this error in flutter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think request body should encoded to a Json string using JsonEncode(Object)
so it should be that way :

```
final http.Response response = await http.post(
      BASE_URL + "item",
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(jsonob),
    );
```

Comment: that didn't work, I managed to fix it by removing all the jsonencode except the first one